# MySQL DISTINCT and whitespace

Tags: mysql, distinct

Consider the following queries

```
INSERT INTO DummyTable (TextColumn) VALUES ('Text');
INSERT INTO DummyTable (TextColumn) VALUES ('Text ');

SELECT DISTINCT TextColumn FROM DummyTable
```

Notice that the second insert contains a whitespace: 'Text '

But DISTINCT ignores the space and returns only one row 'Text' - how do you make DISTINCT not to ignore the whitespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was looking for a BINARY keyword, the DISTINCT then compares raw binary values, including spaces.

```
SELECT DISTINCT BINARY TextColumn FROM DummyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT replace(TextColumn,' ','') FROM DummyTable
```